# Can we subscribe an email ID or Cell number as subscriber to Azure event hubs/notification hubs?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub, azure-eventhub

In my python application, if any bad/good event happens, I want to send the event details as notification message to user's email addresses or phone #s that have been subscribed to this application. So I am looking for publisher-subscriber model azure cloud

Looks like multiple Azure services achieving similar goal but having a thin line of differences. Event hubs and notification hubs seems promising. So my question is as follows:

Can email ID/phone # be subscribed to Azure event hub and receive the message being sent/produced to Azure event hub?

If not event hub, what is the correct option? Can I achieve it with Service bus or Notification hub?

In AWS, there is a service called SNS (Simple Notification Service) where one can subscribe email/phone number and opt for receiving event messages about that application. I am looking for equivalent to that in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) / [Azure Functions with Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) to achieve this easily.

Using logic apps you can do like simple as below image.

[image]

Logic Apps has many in-build connectors for most all Azure Services, you can use [Event-hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs),[Service bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus),[SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) etc.,

You can find all the list of available connectors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list#managed-api-connectors)

**Update 1**

Once you connected the Event-Hubs to send an Email connector, you will automatically get all the available source data from event-hubs to email task. See below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for information. This achieves the purpose.. but how do you put all event information/message in email body?

Comment: @ForeverLearner See the Updated answer. Once you tried yourself. You will get more information.

Comment: Yes. I tried it. But did not see content option for event hub. I will try again. Though, I did see content option for service bus.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Azure Application Insights. With this, you will be able to monitor your application and receive alerts during application unavailabillity, failures or even during performance issue.

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-alert

Comment: hi @rahul .. looks like  app insights is designed to notify users for more of alerts and reports..not naturally designed to send event notification messages to users..I guess it will need some tweaking to make it work. also from documentation, can not understand how I can make it work to simply send notifications.