# Azure notify app when element inserted into table

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

The idea is we have a mobile app backed by an azure database. I am wondering if there is any way to send a notification to the mobile app in case an element has been added to a specific table. The app will receive this notification, check what value has been inserted into that azure sql table and then make a decision whether to send a warning to the app user or not, like a push notification.

Can this be achieved and if yes how ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does my below answer helpful? please accept the accept in such case, so that it can help others

Comment: Thanks @Jayendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you can use [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) which have many connectors for Azure services.

For an instance.

When an item is inserted in a particular table [Azure SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure), it will trigger the job. You can connect that trigger to [send SMS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-alert-to-text-message-with-logic-app/) to the mobile.

[image]

You can also use [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) but current it's doesn't have a SQL Trigger. There is a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881107/7073340) post which deals with the solution for Azure function

For some reference see my answer in this [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263143/7073340)